# iPhone: Not getting image path URL in didFinishPickingImage

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to get image path after picked from photo album using the below code. But it always gives image path as NULL/crash. What is the reason? Could someone help me?

```
    -(IBAction) LaunchAlbum :(id) sender
{
    // Updated - overlay code.
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    appDelegate.pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.pickerController.delegate = self;
    //appDelegate.pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
    //appDelegate.pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"];

    appDelegate.pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.pickerController animated:YES];
    [ appDelegate.pickerController release];
}
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
imageUrl = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]; // CRASH
selectedImage = [imageUrl path];
    NSLog(@"selectedImage: %@", selectedImage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   NSURL* imageUrl = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
   selectedImage = [imageUrl path];
   NSLog(@"selectedImage: %@", selectedImage);
}
```

There were several problems with what you were trying:

1. `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is deprecated
2. Keys like `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` are constants that should be used as is, not quoted as strings.
3. You probably want `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue
?

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is to find out the video file path, not the image file path.

Answer (score 0):

From UIImagePickerController class reference:
editingInfo
A dictionary containing any relevant editing information. If editing is disabled, this parameter is nil. The keys for this dictionary are listed in “Editing information keys.”

Uncomment line appDelegate.pickerController.allowsEditing = NO; 
and editInfo will not be nil.

Comment: Hi, I uncommented  appDelegate.pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;, but still image path is NULL. But i made sure i'm getting the proper image by adding the image in an imageview. The image path URL is NULL still.

Comment: @Getsy, debug your app! Check if editInfo is nil or no. Then NSLog whole editInfo to see what does it have.

Comment: It is not NULL. It is giving like this->      {
    UIImagePickerControllerCropRect = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {147, 140}}";
    UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage = "<UIImage: 0x7336f60>";
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x734fa30>";
}

Comment: @Getsy, you could see now there is no UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL key there. That the reason why nil is returned when you request value for that key from dictionary editInfo.

Comment: I changed to "UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL" as per @adpalumbo sugegsted.

Comment: I changed back to UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL, but still the same issue.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue
?